# json_encode Adds NULL to end of JSON Output

Tags: json, null

The following function successfully returns the expected JSON from my WordPress table but a "null" is added at the end of the string.  I've tried a number of the suggestions here at stackoverflow but nothing works.  Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
function see_get_basic_accuracy() {
  global $wpdb;

  $userid = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
  wp_set_current_user( $userid );
  $userID = get_current_user_id();

  $sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM basic_accuracy_table
    WHERE user_id = $userID
    ORDER BY recent_session ASC
    LIMIT 1;
    ";

  $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  $json = json_encode($results);

  echo $json;
}
```

Here's the output:

[{"id":"4264","Session_Count":"700","Session":"Session - 700","Session_Date":"2018-01-04 16:00:06","user_id":"1","difficulty":"Basic","tot_pct":"32","tot_abs":"8","length_pct":"20","width_pct":"20","angle_pct":"0","curvature_pct":"80","location_pct":"40","length_abs":"1","width_abs":"1","angle_abs":"0","curvature_abs":"4","location_abs":"2","lead_value":null,"Recent_Session":"1","comb_label":"700, 1/4/2018, 4:00 PM, na, na, na","comb_label_ordered":"700, 1/4/2018, 4:00 PM, na, na, na, 1, 1, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 20, 20, 0, 80, 40, 32"}]null

Comment: what will result if your echo `$results`

Comment: @AswinRamesh, the output is: Arraynull